# If $W$ and $\hat{W}$ are isometric and $W$ and $\hat{W}$ dense in $V$ and $\hat{V}$ respectively, then are $V$ and $\hat{V}$ isometric?

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

Let $V$ and $\hat{V}$ be metric spaces and $W$ and $\hat{W}$ subsets of these spaces.

> If $W$ and $\hat{W}$ are isometric and $W$ and $\hat{W}$ dense in $V$ and $\hat{V}$ respectively, then are $V$ and $\hat{V}$ isometric?

Some definitions:

Two metric spaces are isometric if there is a bijection
between points of the metric space and if under the bijection $T$, we have $d(x,y) = \hat{d}(Tx, Ty)$ where $T$ is the bijection.

---

$A$ is dense in $B$ if for any point $x \in B$ and any neighborhood of $x$ $$B(x, \delta) = \{ y | d(x,y) < \delta \}$$ for $\delta > 0$, we have $B(x,\delta) \cap A \not = \emptyset$.

**My thoughts:**

We need to distinguish between two cases:

where $o_1, o_2 \in W$ and $n_1, n_2 \in X \setminus W$

where $\hat{o_1}, \hat{o_2} \in \hat{W}$ and $\hat{n_1}, \hat{n_2} \in \hat{X} \setminus \hat{W}$

1)
Given $o_1$ and $n_1$, we get $\hat{o_1}$ from $T(o_1)$. We must show there is some $\hat{n_1}$ so that
 $$d(o_1, n_1) = d(\hat{o_1}, \hat{n_1})$$

Now map $n_1 \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{T} \hat{n_1}$

2)
Given $n_1$ and $n_2$ show there are some $\hat{n_1}$ and $\hat{n_2}$
so that

$$d(n_1, n_2) = d(\hat{n_1}, \hat{n_2})$$

Now map $n_1 \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{T} \hat{n_1}$ and

$n_2 \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{T} \hat{n_2}$

The mappings must be done in such a way that $T$ remains a bijection. My trouble is to show the existence of such $\hat{n_i}$. I have not yet used this bit about being dense. Perhaps that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. Take $W=\hat{W}=V=(0,1)$ and $\hat{V}=[0,1]$ (with the usual metric).

Comment: You are correct. Kreyszig (in Introductory Functional Analysis) seems to rely on the affirmative (now shown false) of this question to prove theorem 1.6-2d (unless I am misunderstanding his logic)

Comment: In my example, $V$ and $\hat V$ are not topological vector spaces. Besides, if my answer was useful for you, perhaps that you might express it clicking on the up arrow.

Answer (score 2):

If $V$ is the completion of $W$ and $\hat{V}$ is the completion of $\hat{W}$, this is true. Completion is uniquely determined up to isometry by a dense subset; this is typically proven while proving that the space of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences completes a given metric space. For reference: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nironi/completion.pdf

I am unfamiliar with Kreyszig, but this might be the fact it relies upon?

Comment: This is exactly what I need. If I can enlist your help further, would you know why in theorem 2, at the end the following is true : Since $\varphi_1[X]$ is dense in $X_1^*$, we have $g \circ f = i_{X_1^*}$.

Comment: We know that $f,g$ are continuous, so $g\circ f: X^*_1 \to X^*_1$ is continuous. We can easily see that it is the identity on $\varphi_1[X]$. Now, we know the value of a continuous function on a dense subset, so we can uniquely determine the function on the whole space; thus, $g\circ f$ is the identity on $X_1^*$

Comment: This does it. As your explanation points out, it is useful to know a bit about general topology. In particular, a theorem states that if $f: A \rightarrow C$ is continuous and $C$ is Hausdorff, then the continuous function $g: \bar{A} \rightarrow C$ is uniquely determined by $f$. Thanks. I have upvoted your answer but marked the previous one as correct, since it addresses the title question (although you have unearthed the real question I should have posted)

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!